# list alternative for data list firebase to swift ui

Tags: firebase, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to create a custom styled list for my firebase data but can only figure it out with a list view not a vstack or scroll view. is there any way to do this?

I have tried replacing the the list with a VStack/scroll view:

```
 var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(dataManager.lessons, id: \.id) { lesson in \\ I tried changing "list" to "VStack" and "ScrollView"
                let core = lesson.core.components(separatedBy: ",")
                let coreV = Int(core[0]) ?? 0
                let coreW = Int(core[1]) ?? 0
                let coreS = Int(core[2]) ?? 0
                NavigationLink(destination: ScrollView {
                    HomeWorkobjectView(core: coreV, lesson: lesson.vocab, type: "vocab")
                    HomeWorkobjectView(core: coreW, lesson: lesson.work, type: "work")
                    HomeWorkobjectView(core: coreS, lesson: lesson.submissions, type: "work to hand in")
                }.toolbar {
                    Text(lesson.name).font(.title3)
                }) {
                        Text(lesson.name)
                        .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .cornerRadius(buttonCorners)
                        .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.horizontal/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("homework")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `ForEach` loop, such as: `ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(dataManager.lessons, id: \.id) { lesson in
                        // ...
            }`

Comment: no, I didn't know I could do it that way thanks @workingdogsupportUkraine

Answer (score 0):

here is the fix I found from the comments:
I changed the list for a scroll view with a for loop inside

```
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(dataManager.lessons, id: \.id) { lesson in
                        let core = lesson.core.components(separatedBy: ",")
                        let coreV = Int(core[0]) ?? 0
                        let coreW = Int(core[1]) ?? 0
                        let coreS = Int(core[2]) ?? 0
                        NavigationLink(destination: ScrollView {
                            HomeWorkobjectView(core: coreV, lesson: lesson.vocab, type: "vocab")
                            HomeWorkobjectView(core: coreW, lesson: lesson.work, type: "work")
                            HomeWorkobjectView(core: coreS, lesson: lesson.submissions, type: "work to hand in")
                        }.toolbar {
                            Text(lesson.name).font(.title3)
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Text(lesson.name)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("foreground-text"))
                                Spacer()
                            }.padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=View@*/Color("midground-list")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .cornerRadius(buttonCorners)
                                .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.horizontal/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("homework")
                }
            }
        }
```